# User input range for XY graph

Tags: input, range, labview

I'm a beginner user of labview so bear with me, please.  I'm working on a project that takes a data text file with columns and rows as an input.  I have the project set up so far to take the data from that file and display it in an XY graph.

I want to add a feature where the user inputs a set of values that represent a range in the x-scale.  The program should take those two values and make a new graph (or use the old one, that works too) with the proper scale.

I greatly appreciate your time and help .
Thanks

Edit :

[image: Snippet of the txt file]
A snippet of the txt file.

[image: This is the diagrame]

The red arrow shows what I tried to use from the help section of labview.  Yet I have little to no idea on how to integrate it into my diagram or vet if its the right tool to use.

[image: This is the front panel]
These numeric values input in the front panel is what I thought could work, but I'm all ears to any suggestions.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, could you please provide a minimal example of what your code looks like at the moment and say what you already tried? It is easier to help you and people are more willing to help you if they see that you already put some effort in it :)

Comment: Hi Salome , Thx for the feedback , I updated te post with a couple of screenshots , the first graph is the frequencies over time (max time is 395 ) , the second one is the variation of the frequencis for each concentration . What I'm trying to acheive is to have a way to take values that the user inputs and set them as the scale for the first graphs. Say I choose the min time to be 50 and the max is 300 , the graphs should only show the segement of that range and nothing else. Hopefully I succeded to get the idea out , if not I'm more than available to add any informations needed :) .

Answer (score 3):

You already found the correct property node value :)

[image]

You have to connect a minimum and a maximum value to the property node. If you click on the function on the node, you can select the min and max option.

I made this little example for you to see what you need to do.
Property nodes are in genereal very useful as you can set and change so many settings programatically.

A nice feature of LabVIEW: You can drag&drop .png pictures in your Block Diagram. So if you want to test my VI-Snippet, just drag&drop it :)

I hope that I could help you, feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: And one more thing, if you want to ensure the order of your functions, just use the error wire and connect everything in the order you want :)

Comment: Hi, thx for you help , I know now how the property node works . Is there a way to x scale to the graph i already have , i want to have the data from the original graph (getting the linear function) ,thx for answer.

Comment: So you want to scale your graph (1) or do you want to get the scale (2) of it? And do you want to get all of the data that you have in your graph (3)?
(1): Use the property node like this, but link it to your graph. Y
(2): Use the same property but change it to read (Right click the property and select 'Change to Read'

(3): Use the property "Value" and change it to read. (Right click the property and select 'Change to Read'